Laravel + api platform and snake case
I'm using Laravel and API platform (https://api-platform.com/).
By Laravel convetion and mysql convetion column names in table should be snake_case, but API platform requires camelCase. I found this
In API Platform, if your entities are using snake_case for variable names, but the framework expects camelCase by default, this mismatch can cause issues. By default, API Platform uses the Symfony Serializer, which expects properties in camelCase.

I tried to add this
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(
            normalizationContext: [
                'groups' => ['Brand:list'],
                'name_converter' => CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter::class,
            ],
        ),
        new Get(
            normalizationContext: [
                'groups' => ['Brand:read'],
                'name_converter' => CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter::class,
            ],
        )
    ],
    normalizationContext: [
        'groups' => ['Brand:read'],
        'name_converter' => CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter::class,
    ],
    denormalizationContext: [
        'groups' => ['Brand:write'],
        'name_converter' => CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter::class,
    ]
)]

But that is not working. In my table I have one column called local_name, and when I try to GET collection, I get all field but not that one. Did anyone else found solution how to get column names with snake_case. Also I have a getter getLocalName that returns $this->local_name, but it is not working. I'm missing something.
